# Error: char converts between pointers to integer types with different sign

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

**Question:** Write a program anagram that sorts the letters in a word, which is useful when searching for anagrams. anagram takes a single argument, which is a string containing only lower-case letters, sorts the letters alphabetically, and then prints the sorted letters. You may use any sorting algorithm you are familiar with, but you must write the sort function yourself. You may not use any sort function provided by a library.

Usage

```
$ ./anagram hello
ehllo
$ ./anagram positivity
iiiopsttvy
$ ./anagram abcdef
abcdef
```

The below code is what I have done so far but I get the error

> passing char * to parameter of unsigned char converts between pointers to integer types with different sign

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void anagram(unsigned char input[])
{
   int count[256] = { 0 };
   int i;
   for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
      count[input[i]]++;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
   {
      while (count[i] > 0)
      {
         printf("%c", i);
         count[i]--;
      }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if(argc > 1)
   {
      anagram(argv[1]);
   }
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: `argv[1]` is `char*`. `anagram` takes `unsigned char*`

Comment: where should I put the `unsigned char*`

Comment: Why would you put `unsigned char *` anywhere to begin with when you are manipulating *nul-terminated* strings? Just use `void anagram (char *input)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer to your question is you are getting the pointer sign mismatch warning because you are attempting to pass `argv[1]` (type `char *`) to `anagram` which you have declared with a parameter of `unsigned char *` (though you use `input[]`, the practical effect is that `input` decays to a pointer when used as a parameter)

The simple solution while preserving the `unsigned char*` type for `anagram` is to cast `argv[1]` to `(unsigned char *)` when passed as a parameter to `anagram`, e.g.

```
    anagram((unsigned char *)argv[1]);
```

The more practical question is "Do you really need the `unsigned char*` type to begin with?" While you can escape and pass non-ASCII values as the argument to your program -- is that something you expect and want to protect against by using the `unsigned char*` (which is 100% fine to do).

Generally, you would simply declare `anagram (char *input)` (which is your second alternative to eliminate the signed mismatch on the pointers) and limit your loop to looping over the valid range for ASCII characters (see [ASCIItable.com](http://asciitable.com))

Either way is fine so long as you handle the pointer signedness consistently. Putting that altogether and removing the *magic numbers* from your code, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CHRSET 256      /* if you need a constant, define one */

void anagram (unsigned char *input)
{
    int i, count[CHRSET] = { 0 };

    for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
        count[input[i]]++;

    for (i = 0; i < CHRSET; i++)
        while (count[i] > 0) {
            printf("%c", i);
            count[i]--;
        }
    putchar ('\n');   /* provide a POSIX compliant newline before termination */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input\n"
                         "usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    anagram ((unsigned char *)argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you can also move the output of the final newline to `main`, but unless you plan on smushing multiple sorted strings together by making repeated calls to `anagram`, then it is better left after the output of each string)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.